# Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ and $E ⊂ K$. Suppose that $E$ is closed relative to $K$. Prove or disprove that $E$ is closed relative to $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

To prove or disprove that $E$ is closed in $X$, I thought $X \smallsetminus E$ should be open in $X$.
$$(X \smallsetminus E)=(X \smallsetminus K) \cup (K \smallsetminus E)$$
$X \smallsetminus K$ is open since $K$ is compact in $X$, which means that $K$ is closed in $X$.
$K \smallsetminus E$ is also open since $E$ is closed relative to $K$.
Union of open sets are open, so $X \smallsetminus E$ is open.

But I think the answer should be $E$ is not closed relative to $X$.
I can't find the problem in my proof and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What is $X$? A subspace of $\mathbb{R}$? An arbitrary topological space?

Comment: X is just a simple nonempty metric space. Not particularly a subspace of R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your space $X$ is Hausdorff then $E$ is closed relative to $X$ since $K$ is then closed. But if $X$ is for example infinite set with cofinite topology then $E$ doesn't need to be closed relative to $X$, because in this space every set is compact and there are non-closed sets.

Comment: X is just a nonempty metric space. I haven't learned about Hausdorff space yet. In that space, does compact set that is non closed exists?

Comment: No. In a Husdorff space every compact set is closed. If $E$ is closed in $K$ then $E=K\cap F$ for some closed set $F$ in $X$. Now, $K$ and $F$ are both closed in $X$ and their intersection is closed in $X$. Does this help?

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If $E$ is closed in $K$, then it is compact, since $K$ is compact. Therefore, $E$ is closed in $X$.